# Is it possible to open two socket connections - one text and one binary - in one R session?

Tags: r, sockets

I'm trying to write an R program that maintains a socket connection between two different machines and, while that socket for text communication is open, opens a second socket to transfer a file. However, this doesn't seem to work across two separate machines.

To test this, I wrote this basic example:

**test-server.R**

```
textSocket <- socketConnection(host="192.168.56.101", port=9998, blocking=TRUE, server=TRUE, encoding="utf-8", timeout=300, open="r+")

fileSize <- as.integer(readLines(textSocket, 1))

binSocket <- socketConnection(host="192.168.56.101", port=9999, blocking=TRUE, server=TRUE, timeout=15, open="rb")
fileData <- readBin(binSocket, "raw", n=fileSize)
close(binSocket)

outFile <- file("fromClient.txt", open="wb")
writeBin(fileData, outFile)
close(outFile)

close(textSocket)
```

**test-client.R**

```
textSocket <- socketConnection(host="192.168.56.101", port=9998, server=FALSE, blocking=TRUE, encoding="utf-8", timeout=86400, open="r+")

fileSize <- as.integer(file.info("toServer.txt")$size)
writeLines(toString(fileSize), textSocket)

inFile <- file("toServer.txt", open="rb")
fileData <- readBin(inFile, "raw", n=fileSize)
close(inFile)

binSocket <- socketConnection(host="192.168.56.101", port=9999, blocking=TRUE, server=FALSE, timeout=300, open="rb")
writeBin(fileData, binSocket)
close(binSocket)

close(textSocket)
```

For the sake of brevity, I have removed all the print statements that I used to confirm which specific line was the problem.

If I put both of these files (and toServer.txt) on the machine on "192.168.56.101" and then run both files on two separate R sessions with source(), the whole thing works perfectly. A "fromClient.txt" file appears in my working directory containing exactly what I expected, and no warnings or errors are printed.

However, if I instead run the **test-client.R** file on a different machine (on 192.168.56.102), then the files execute up until the line where `binSocket` is created. And then they give me the following errors:

**Client side** (gives me the error first):

```
Error in socketConnection(host = "192.168.56.101", port = 9999, blocking = TRUE,  :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = "192.168.56.101", port = 9999, blocking = TRUE,  :
  192.168.56.101:9999 cannot be opened
```

**Server side**

```
Error in socketConnection(host = "192.168.56.101", port = 9999, blocking = TRUE,  :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = "192.168.56.101", port = 9999, blocking = TRUE,  :
  problem in listening on this socket
```

(For context, both of these are virtual machines on the Virtualbox "host only network" setting. Both machines are running Ubuntu 22 with R and R studio installed. Also, there are no processes running on ports 9998 or 9999, I can change those and I still get this issue.)

So what gives? Does R just not allow sessions to create two simultaneous sockets? I couldn't find anything like that mentioned in the docs or in any other threads, though in fairness there don't seem to be many people doing socket work with base R.

UPDATE: So I still don't think it's possible to have two sockets open, but as it turns out, I don't need that to send files alongside text! If I open the main socket (`textSocket` in the code) with the parameter `open="r+b"`, then I can send both text and binary data across the socket. I can use `readLines()`, `writeLines()`, `readBin()`, and `writeBin()`, all on the same socket as long as I'm keeping track of sizes.

Comment: A guess: what if the server hasn't created binSocket yet by the time the client tries to connect to it?

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue. I just added a pause for user input in the client, just before the binSocket creation. No matter how long I wait before I hit the enter key, I get the same error on the client. (And if I wait long enough, the server gives me the same error regardless of whether the client even tried to connect.) Besides, I've seen those "server socket not listening" errors before, they give me a different message.